# How can I convert this code from vb. net to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to convert vb .net code to c# but I am having problem with the following code:

```
Dim MI_Display_Channel As New MethodInvoker(AddressOf display_channel)

Private Sub display_channel()
    TextBox1.Text = fv_channel
End Sub
```

How can I convert this piece of code into c#?

Comment: I'm surprised this question isn't closed yet.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: If you're having a problem with the code, how will converting it to C# help? It'll still be the same code with the same problem!

Comment: Oh. That's not what I thought given the text of the question.

Answer (score 4):

I see two answers machine translated where, apparently, a field initializer of an instance field, refers an instance member of the class. That is not allowed.

To be explicit:

```
class Xxx
{
  MethodInvoker MI_Display_Channel = display_channel; // compile-time error!

  void display_channel()
  {
    TextBox1.Text = fv_channel;
  }
}
```

will not compile. When the field initialization is not allowed in a field initializer, use a constructor:

```
class Xxx
{
  public Xxx()  // other instance constructors may want to chain  : this()
  {
    MI_Display_Channel = display_channel; // fine
  }

  MethodInvoker MI_Display_Channel; // no initializer here

  void display_channel()
  {
    TextBox1.Text = fv_channel;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/?batchId=afb6916d-e215-4532-b7aa-a0e3a658716c), you get this:

```
MethodInvoker MI_Display_Channel = new MethodInvoker(display_channel);
private void display_channel()
{
    TextBox1.Text = fv_channel;
}
```

I'm not sure why it was difficult.

Comment: It looks like a field initializer on an instance field where another instance member (on `this`) is used. That is not allowed. Please try compiling it! Saying `new DelegateType(...)` is quite redundant; method group conversion can be used. Why does one instance member use redundant `private` modifier while another instance member omits it? See also my answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes you have a good point - I didn't try to compile and should have. Your answer is better so you'll get my upvote. I'll leave this here just for the conversion link.